# MediaWiki 1.29. Как установить внешние зависимости?

Tags: php, mediawiki

**Используется**
Windows 7;
Сервер - OpenSerwer;
Apache - 2.42 x64;
Php - 5.5 x64;
MySql - 5.7 x64;

Пробую установить MediaWiki 1.29.
На начальной странице сообщение:

"**MediaWiki 1.29 internal error**
Installing some external dependencies (e.g. via composer) is required.

**External dependencies**
MediaWiki now also has some external dependencies that need to be installed via composer or from a separate git repo. Please see mediawiki.org for help on installing the required components." **конец сообщения**.

Ссылка в данном сообщении отсылает на следующую [страницу](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download_from_Git#Fetch_external_libraries).
Раздел: **"Fetch external libraries"**.

Не могу разобраться с данной документацией.

**Вопрос.**
В какую папку переходить?
Какую команду вводить в cmd (Консоль Виндовс)?

Answer (score 1):

Установите composer - пакетный менеджер для php. затем наберите

composer install --no-dev

в директории с вики.